# Accept true slightly different values

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

Let's say that we have two examples:

one:

```
a = "Six d.o.g.s."
b = "six d.o.g.s"
```

two:

```
c = "Death Disco"
d = "deathdisco"
e = "deathdisco666"
```

Both are slightly different. The first has one more dot and the second no space in between on the. Some are lowercase.

---

**Objective:**

- For the given `a` and `b` we want `a.lower()==b.lower()` to give `true`
  if they have two letters "error".
- For the `c` and `d` to give true since "error" is only one space.
- But for the `c` and `e`, although the `e` is two more letters in
  length (comparing with `c`) we have three letters different.

How can I do this with python? Via regex or is there a library for similar purpose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given minitech's comment I write the code I found:

```
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    oneago = None
    thisrow = range(1, len(seq2) + 1) + [0]
    for x in xrange(len(seq1)):
        twoago, oneago, thisrow = oneago, thisrow, [0] * len(seq2) + [x + 1]
        for y in xrange(len(seq2)):
            delcost = oneago[y] + 1
            addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + 1
            subcost = oneago[y - 1] + (seq1[x] != seq2[y])
            thisrow[y] = min(delcost, addcost, subcost)
    return thisrow[len(seq2) - 1]


print levenshtein(a,b) < 2
```

Comment: You can `pip install python-Levenshtein` and then `from Levenshtein import distance`